# ¿Por qué la función map no retorna la lista sin valores duplicados?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lista

Tengo esta lista:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Y quiero eliminar los valores duplicados. El código para la función `map` es sacada de [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459748/111110). 
Este es el código de testeo completo:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 6, 6, 7]

list2 = []
map(lambda x: not x in list2 and list2.append(x), list1)
print(list2)

list2 = []
[list2.append(c) for c in list1 if c not in list2]
print(list2)

list2 = []

for c in list1:
    if c not in list2:
        list2.append(c)

print(list2)
```

En Python 2.7 imprime:

> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
>
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
>
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]

En Python 3.4 imprime:

> []
>
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]
>
> [1, 3, 56, 6, 7]

¿Por qué la función `map` retorna una lista vacía en Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python3, `map` es un **iterador**. Como tu código no *consume* el iterador, es como si no hicera nada.

La forma más simple de *consumir* el iterador es convertirlo en lista:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 56, 6, 6, 6, 7]

list2 = []
list(map(lambda x: not x in list2 and list2.append(x), list1))
print(list2)
```

En mi opinión, no deberías emplear las comprensiones de listas para efectos colaterales.

Para hacer lo que quieres hay un modo más elegante (siempre que la intención sea eliminar los repetidos que estén seguidos):

```
from itertools import groupby

list2 = [x for (x,_) in groupby(list1)]
```

Un método que elimina todos los duplicados y conserva el orden:

```
list2 = sorted(set(list1), key=list1.index)
```